# javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert: unrecognized_name on java 1.8

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, sni

My eclipse plugin application still gets SSLProtocolException: handshake alert:  unrecognized_name on java version "1.8.0_141" although I followed some tips to disable SNI extension already.

```
[INFO] Property jsse.enableSNIExtension=false
[FATAL] javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert:  unrecognized_name
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.handshakeAlert(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
```

Please help me on this case, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The unrecognized_name alert might be sent back by the server if the name sent with SNI is unexpected. But it might also be sent back if the server requires SNI to be used and no server name was sent by the client. Disabling SNI like you do can thus trigger the second case, i.e. the server requires SNI but the client does not provide it.

The correct way to deal with this error is to use the SNI extension and set the name to the one expected by the server.